# jQuery multiple tables row separate in pages for print

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i want to divide multiple tables row in separate pages when print. 
First table rows separate complete then start next table rows separate and each page can contain 21rows

Any help with this is very much appreciated

```js
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
 for (i=0; i<document.getElementsByTagName("table").length; i++)
 {
  document.getElementsByTagName("table")[i].style.pageBreakBefore="always";
  
 }
 
 var div_pageBreaker = '<div style="page-break-before:always;"></div>';
 var per_page = 15;
 $('table').each(function(index, element)
 {
  console.log($(element));
  //how many pages of rows have we got?
  var pages = Math.ceil($('tbody tr').length / per_page);

  //if we only have one page no more
  if (pages == 1) {
   return;
  }
  //get the table we're splutting
  var table_to_split = $(element);

  var current_page   = 1;
  //loop through each of our pages
  for (current_page = 1; current_page <= pages; current_page++) 
  {
   //make a new copy of the table
   var cloned_table = table_to_split.clone();
   //remove rows on later pages
   $('tbody tr', table_to_split).each(function(loop, row_element) {
    //if we've reached our max
    if (loop >= per_page) {
     //get rid of the row
     $(row_element).remove();
    }
   });

   //loop through the other copy
   $('tbody tr', cloned_table).each(function(loop, row_element) {
    //if we are before our current page
    if (loop < per_page) {
     //remove that one
     $(row_element).remove();
    }
   });

   //insert the other table afdter the copy
   if (current_page < pages) {
    $(div_pageBreaker).appendTo('#appendTable');
    $(cloned_table).appendTo('#appendTable');
   }

   //make a break
   table_to_split = cloned_table;
  }
 });

});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td><h4>Table 1</h4></td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td></tr>
  <tr><td>9</td></tr>
  <tr><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr><td>11</td></tr>
  <tr><td>12</td></tr>
  <tr><td>13</td></tr>
  <tr><td>14</td></tr>
  <tr><td>15</td></tr>
  <tr><td>16</td></tr>
 
 </tbody>
</table>

<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td><h4>Table 2</h4></td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td></tr>
  <tr><td>9</td></tr>
  <tr><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr><td>11</td></tr>
  <tr><td>12</td></tr>
  <tr><td>13</td></tr>
  <tr><td>14</td></tr>
  <tr><td>15</td></tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
 <div id="appendTable"></div>
```

Comment: Where are the 

`</tr>`

of Each table

`<tbody>`

 row?

Comment: See this [Sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/pqIWJ66DFrO9w6LUHC3X?p=preview).

Comment: ooopss!!!  
added now but its not working.. two blank pages are print out

Comment: check my answer

Comment: checked it but why the table2 comes up beofre table1 separate complete

Comment: check it now it updated as you wanted [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/pqIWJ66DFrO9w6LUHC3X?p=preview)

Sorry for being late i was busy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the last code updated and blank pages are removed:-

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("table").length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("table")[i].style.pageBreakBefore = "always";

  }

  var div_pageBreaker = '<div style="page-break-before:always;"></div>';
  var per_page = 15;
  $('table').each(function(index, element) {
    debugger;
    console.log($(element));
    //how many pages of rows have we got?
    //EDIT:?????????????????????????????????
    var pages = Math.ceil($(element).find('tbody tr').length / per_page);

    //if we only have one page no more
    if (pages == 1) {
      return;
    }
    //get the table we're splutting
    var table_to_split = $(element);

    var current_page = 1;
    //loop through each of our pages
    for (current_page = 1; current_page <= pages; current_page++) {
      //make a new copy of the table
      var cloned_table = table_to_split.clone();
      //remove rows on later pages
      $('tbody tr', table_to_split).each(function(loop, row_element) {
        //if we've reached our max
        if (loop >= per_page) {
          //get rid of the row
          $(row_element).remove();
        }
      });

      //loop through the other copy
      $('tbody tr', cloned_table).each(function(loop, row_element) {
        //if we are before our current page
        if (loop < per_page) {
          //remove that one
          $(row_element).remove();
        }
      });

      //insert the other table afdter the copy
      if (current_page < pages) {
        //check here if the table has trs then append else do nothing
        if (cloned_table.find('tbody tr').length > 0) {
          //EDIT:?????????????????????????????????
          $(div_pageBreaker).appendTo($(element));
          $(cloned_table).appendTo($(element));
        }
      }

      //make a break
      table_to_split = cloned_table;
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>Table 1</h4></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>15</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>16</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>Table 2</h4></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>15</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div id="appendTable"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Edit**:
This is a working [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/pqIWJ66DFrO9w6LUHC3X?p=preview)
Hope this answers your Question.

Comment: Thank you this  helped a lot but why the table 2 comes up before table1 separate completes

Comment: answer is updated as you want

Please Upvote and mark as answer.