# Jquery Multiple Table Rows Divide in separate Pages When Printing

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have multiple table like these [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZEMT.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGvcr.png) i want to divide these table rows in separate pages. each page contain 15 or 20 rows, after 1st table complete separating then the 2nd table will start. these code repeat the head text on next page when printing i want to remove it.

please help

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("testInfoTable").length; i++) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("testInfoTable")[i].style.pageBreakBefore = "always";

      }
      var div_pageBreaker = '<div style="page-break-before:always;"></div>';
      var per_page = 15;
   
      $('.testInfoTable').each(function(index, element) {
        var pages = Math.ceil($(element).find('tbody tr').length / per_page);

         if (pages == 1) {
          return;
        }
        var table_to_split = $(element);

        var current_page = 1;
        
  for (current_page = 1; current_page <= pages; current_page++) {
          
    var cloned_table = table_to_split.clone();
          
    $('tbody tr', table_to_split).each(function(loop, row_element) {
            
   if (loop >= per_page) {
              
     $(row_element).remove();
            }
          });

          
    $('tbody tr', cloned_table).each(function(loop, row_element) {
            
   if (loop < per_page) {
              
     $(row_element).remove();
            }
          });

          
    if (current_page < pages) {
            if (cloned_table.find('tbody tr').length > 0) {
              
     $(element).find(".text").html("What");
    $(cloned_table).find("h4").html("What");
    $(div_pageBreaker).appendTo($(element));
    $(cloned_table).appendTo($(element));
     
            }
          }

          //make a break
          table_to_split = cloned_table;
        }
      });

    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<body>
  
<div>

  <table class="testInfoTable">
    <thead>
  <tr><th> Table 1 Head 1</th> </tr>
  <tr><th> <div>Table 1 Head 2</div></th> </tr>
  <tr><th> <div>Table 1 Head 3</div></th> </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>
    <h4 class="text">Head Text : Table 1</h4>
   </th>
  </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  <tr><td>1</td> <td>1</td> <td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td> <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>3</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>4</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>5</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>6</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>7</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>8</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>9</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>10</td> <td>1</td> <td>1</td>  </tr>
  <tr><td>11</td> <td>1</td> <td>1</td>  </tr>
  <tr><td>12</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>13</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>14</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>15</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>16</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>17</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>18</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>19</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>20</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>21</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>22</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>23</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>24</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>25</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>26</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>27</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>28</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>29</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>30</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>31</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>32</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
 </tbody>
  </table>

  <table class="testInfoTable">
    <thead>
  <tr><th> Table 2 Head 1</th> </tr>
  <tr><th> <div>Table 2 Head 2</div></th> </tr>
  <tr><th> <div>Table 2 Head 3</div></th> </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>
    <h4 class="text">Head Text : Table 2</h4>
   </th>
  </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  <tr><td>1</td> <td>1</td> <td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td> <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>3</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>4</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>5</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>6</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>7</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>8</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>9</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>10</td> <td>1</td> <td>1</td>  </tr>
  <tr><td>11</td> <td>1</td> <td>1</td>  </tr>
  <tr><td>12</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>13</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>14</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>15</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>16</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>17</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>18</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>19</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>20</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>21</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>22</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>23</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>24</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>25</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>26</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>27</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>28</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>29</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>30</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>31</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>32</td>  <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
 </tbody>
  </table>
  <div id="appendTable"></div>
 </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery multiple tables row separate in pages for print](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42003471/jquery-multiple-tables-row-separate-in-pages-for-print)

Comment: if (current_page < pages) 
{
 if (cloned_table.find('tbody tr').length > 0)
 { 
            $(div_pageBreaker).appendTo($(element));
             $(cloned_table).appendTo($(element));
 }
}

this code not get the css style...
and the code repeat the head text while printing the second page

Answer (score 0):

Check this i add a code to delete the header of the cloned table:-

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("testInfoTable").length; i++) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("testInfoTable")[i].style.pageBreakBefore = "always";

    }
    var div_pageBreaker = '<div style="page-break-before:always;"></div>';
    var per_page = 15;

    $('.testInfoTable').each(function(index, element) {
      var pages = Math.ceil($(element).find('tbody tr').length / per_page);

      if (pages == 1) {
        return;
      }
      var table_to_split = $(element);

      var current_page = 1;

      for (current_page = 1; current_page <= pages; current_page++) {

        var cloned_table = table_to_split.clone();

        //cloned_table.find('thead').remove();

        $('tbody tr', table_to_split).each(function(loop, row_element) {

          if (loop >= per_page) {

            $(row_element).remove();
          }
        });


        $('tbody tr', cloned_table).each(function(loop, row_element) {

          if (loop < per_page) {

            $(row_element).remove();
          }
        });


        if (current_page < pages) {
          if (cloned_table.find('tbody tr').length > 0) {

            $(element).find(".text").html("What");
            $(cloned_table).find("h4").html("What");
            //Edit?????????
            table_to_split.after(div_pageBreaker, cloned_table);


          }
        }

        //make a break
        table_to_split = cloned_table;
      }
    });

  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

  <body>

    <div>

      <table class="testInfoTable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th> Table 1 Head 1</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <div>Table 1 Head 2</div>
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <div>Table 1 Head 3</div>
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <h4 class="text">Head Text : Table 1</h4>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>17</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>24</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>26</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>31</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>32</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <table class="testInfoTable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th> Table 2 Head 1</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <div>Table 2 Head 2</div>
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <div>Table 2 Head 3</div>
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <h4 class="text">Head Text : Table 2</h4>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>17</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>24</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>26</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>31</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>32</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div id="appendTable"></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this solve your Issue

Here is a full [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/lJGPuZGj55xv9CuuoE2M?p=preview)

Comment: i didn't want to remove the head text. the head text shows duplicate with a blank page when print. i want to remove that

Comment: I have updated the answer and the demo, and I checked it on Chrome, Please check it.